# How can I change the default usage rights settings of the Google Images search?

Tags: google-image-search

I would like the default setting to be **Labeled for reuse**. How can I make this setting apply permanently?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been seeking this for a long time and have yet to find an extension or modifier that will change the defaults image search uses.

My only solution so far was to create a search engine I enter in chrome, with a shortcut `gcc` (or whatever works for you) and for the query URL:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&tbm=isch&tbs=il%3Acl&hl=en
```

This means in the URL bar I can enter `gcc` TAB then enter search terms.

It works great, but if I modify the search at all, it reverts to those default settings. The query parameter for the license settings appears to be for CC search

```
tbs=il%3Acl
```

and for "Commercial and Other Terms" that value is

```
tbs=il:ol
```

I've been using these for years, almost any sites search result can be made into one of these just modifying the results for the search query to be %s

Answer (score 0):

I found a new idea, [install the Requestly extension](https://requestly.io/) which is used to modify URLs.

I have a pattern that looks for urls containing the google image search parameter `tbm=isch` and if it is in the URL, it adds the parameter `tbs=il%3Acl` that makes the results Creative Commons only.

[Import my rule](https://app.requestly.io/rules/#sharedList/1640358040689-CogDog%27s-Google-Image-Search) of create a rule like this

[image]

All google image searches I have tested so far have the CC option enabled -- the only way to not use it is to disable the rule or the extension. If I was better at regex i could maybe find a more elegant rule pattern.

But all my image searches come with CC selected.